# Conveniently import several classes from modules in a Python package

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a framework for a syntax tree. I have a folder/package `syntax` which contains one syntax tree element which is a class in each file, the structure looks then like:

```
syntax/List.py -> contains class List
syntax/Block.py -> contains class Block
syntax/Statement.py -> contains class Statement
```

Now I'd like to import the folder into my source file in a way that I can access the classes like

```
block = syntax.Block()
```

Is that possible at all? So far, I always ended up that I need `syntax.Block.Block()` which is not very nice...

Comment: You should really keep the module names lower case. It's the standard way to do it, and there won't be confusion between the classes and the modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Project structure

```
syntax
├── Block.py
├── __init__.py
```

The class

```
# syntax/Block.py (this file really ought to be lowercase, leave PascalCase to class names)
class Block(object):
    pass
```

Imports in `__init__`

```
# syntax/__init__.py
from .Block import Block   # Relative import with .
```

Using the package

```
In [5]: import syntax

In [6]: b = syntax.Block()

In [7]: b
Out[7]: <syntax.Block.Block at 0x108dcb990>
```

### Alternative if you are open to some re-organization

Unlike languages that *require* us to put a single class into a file with same name (class `Block` inside file `Block.py`), Python is pretty flexible about this.

You can actually put many classes in `syntax.py` and import `syntax` alone, then access `syntax.Block` (no imports in `__init__.py` would be required for this)

```
# syntax.py
class Block(object):
    pass
class List(object):
    pass
```

Then can use as follows

```
import syntax
b = syntax.Block()
l = syntax.List()
```

Answer (score 5):

The most readable way to deal with that is to do your imports into the `__init__.py` file

Example :

```
# syntax/__init__.py
from syntax.List import List
from syntax.Block import Block
from syntax.Statement import Statement

# in your main file
from syntax import List
import syntax
b = syntax.Block()
```

Note: you can also use the relative import syntax in your `__init__.py` file (for example `from .List import List`)

---

When you do an import, you define a variable. This variable is containing your imported variable, constant, function, class or whatever you want.

If you do `from .List import List` into your `__init__.py` file, you are defining the variable `List` into your `__init__.py` file refering to the class `syntax.List.List`.

So when you are trying you write `from syntax import List` you are trying to import the variable `List` from your `__init__.py` file, which point to the `syntax.List.List`.

```
from syntax import List
from syntax.List import List as OriginList

List is OriginList # True
```

Comment: Is that line "in your main file", `from syntax import List` correct?

Comment: I'm afraid that in this case there will be confusion between the class `syntax.List` and the module `syntax.List`. He should really keep his module names lower case (have class List in list.py instead of List.py).

Comment: On my Python version (2.6), it works. Maybe it's not a good solution however. What do you think about it ?

Comment: This is the normal way to do it, except perhaps just putting all three classes into one syntax.py and not bothering splitting them into three modules, that'd probably be the most normal.